# How to apply a function that creates multiple new columns to a pandas dataframe, using a vectorized approach?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I am creating new columns based on some data from another data frame and some data from the dataframe I wish to extend.

I have a working solution but I am interested to learn if there is a vectorized approach, since currently it takes quite some time to use the pandas.apply() methog (which iterates rows under the hood).

The function which performs the transformation:

```
import pandas as pd


def add_new_columns(row, **kwds):
    participant = row['participant']
    time = row['time']

    ### NOTE ###
    # There is some other code here which handles cases where other
    # dataframe does not contain information, in that case we impute

    return pd.Series(kwds['other_df'].loc[participant, time])
```

and the statement which calls the above function:

```
main_df = pd.merge(
    main_df,
    main_df.apply(
        add_new_columns,
        axis=1,
        other_df=other_df
    ),
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True
)
```

A basic example of some datasets that would work with the above code:

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['001', 'P1', 3, 'jumped'],
        ['002', 'P3', 8, 'yawned'],
        ['004', 'P2', 7, 'made something up']
    ],
    columns=['id', 'participant', 'time', 'action']
).set_index('id')

other_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['P1', 3, 2, 9, 8],
        ['P3', 8, 5, 6, 3],
        ['P2', 7, 9, 8, 5]
    ],
    columns=['participant', 'time', 'sugar-levels', 'some-other-measure', 'some-other-measure2']
).set_index(['participant', 'time'])
```

My data is 800,000 lines long. I would like to avoid iteration if possible. Are there other methods in pandas which might help?

Answer (score 0):

You're basically trying to join `other_df` to `main_df` on `participant` and `time`. Without knowing your imputation logic it's hard to give a complete answer, but you could first merge `other_df` like so:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(main_df, other_df, how='left', on=['participant','time'])
```

And then fill in the missing values in the `sugar-levels` column of `merged_df` using an imputation method of your choice.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that strategy. I guess I will update this with an example similar to what I am working with.

To give an idea though. The other_df only has a subset of the 'time' / 'sugar-level' data for each participant. But there is a relationship (logarithmic). So I just need to extrapolate the missing values.

Is there a vectorized approach for that?